# Why does if else statement doesn't work in this program.Please need some explanation ,While i can't move forward in learning

Tags: java, if-statement

```java
package tutorial;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        
        System.out.println("Enter your age:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        
        
        if(age > 13 ) {
            
                
                    System.out.println(" you are a teenager");
                
        }
        if else(age >18) {
                
                System.out.println("You are adult! you can drive");
            }
            
        }
        else {
            
            System.out.println("you cant drive");
        }
```

If enter age as " 21" .It just prints the first if else statement .I just want solution and explanation

Comment: You want "else if" instead of "if else" - it's as simple as that. You've also got too many closing braces in that area.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, although I don't know how and why it compiles since he has no condition specified for the second if. Is it interpreted as if(false)?

Comment: And check your condition. If the age is greater than 13 it will never go into the else if case. Either reorder the statements or use multiple if statements

Comment: @tibetiroka: The code presented here does *not* compile. So whatever the OP is running is certainly not the code that they've shown...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first statement has no conditions on it - if you're 21, you're over 13 - and that's what your condition checks. You never make it to your else conditions. Perhaps start at the oldest condition and work your way downwrds?

Side note, if you're equal to 13, you're not over 13 - your condition checks for over, not over or equal to - thus, 13 year olds would fail your checks here.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has already mentioned, you should use greater or equal to avoid leaving out certain ages. And corsiKa also suggested "Perhaps start at the oldest condition and work your way downwrds?" which is a good idea

```
if(age >= 18)
   System.out.println("Adult");
else if(age >= 13)
   System.out.println("Teen");
else
   System.out.println("Can't drive");
```